Did Gauss really call Archimedes an idiot?
I was watching Numberphile's Parabolas and Archimedes featuring John Ball.
However, it is doubtful whether the Gauss quote quoted at the end of the video by Johnny Ball, "Oh the idiot! He discovered calculus and he let it go through his fingers," is really what Gauss said.
Did Gauss really call Archimedes an idiot?

Gauss was a German speaker.

And a Latin writer

Yukion the answer below seems to solve the issue. Could you validate it?

Too short for me to edit, but he's always known as ‘Johnny’, not ‘John’.  (It's not a diminutive of his birth name, which is actually Graham.  In fact, the nickname refers to the footballer John Ball.)

In Dunnington, G. W., Gray, J., & Dohse, F. E. (2004). Carl Friedrich Gauss: Titan of Science. MAA. p. 218 one finds the following:

Archimedes was the man of antiquity whom Gauss esteemed most highly.
He imagined him as a worthy old man of noble appearance. The only
thing for which he could not pardon him was the fact that in his "sand
calculating" he did not discover the arithmetic of position or decimal
system of numbers. Gauss said, "How could he overlook that, and at
what a pinnacle science would now be if Archimedes had made that
discovery."

(emphasis is mine)
Johnny Ball's version is on some level a sensible paraphrasing of the above translation by Dunnington of 1955. Given that Dunnington is a widely read English text on Gauss it might well be that Ball has it from this passage.
Sadly, Dunnington does not provide a direct citation, so I'm still looking where he might have translated this from. I'll edit this once I find it. EDIT: Mauricio has discovered that the source of Dunnington's passage is likely Wolfgang Sartorius von Waltershausen (1856) Gauss zum Gedächtnis p. 84. This source is known to be hagiographic and contains apocryphal material. So it may well be that this is not an actual Gauss quote. So unless a primary passage can be found it is probably best to consider it unconfirmed.
I take it as virtually certain that the "idiot" part is just flair injected by Ball.
Also note the mathematical context of von Walthershausen, that Dunningworth mentioned and compare it to Ball's exposition. In von Waltershausen it's the "decadische Zahlensystem" (system of decadic numbers, my translation), in Dunnington it is "arithmetic of position or decimal system of numbers" while in Ball's exposition it is calculus. In this sense this type of story telling fits many criteria of the kind of historically false or problematic folklore discussed by many other examples.

Just noting here that Ball quote is about calculus, Dunnington seems to be about the decimal system.

I found the same story in Gauss zum Gedächtnis a memorial written very soon after Gauss' death by Wolfgang Sartorius (1856), the same that wrote the 1+2+...+100 story.

@Mauricio Thanks for pointing out Wolfgang Sartorius von Waltershausen. Dunnington paragraph appears to be a near verbatim translation of a passage of Gauss zum Gedächtnis p. 84. So much so that I think one must assume that this is the source of Dunnington's passage. It is certainly quite possible that this is not a real quote of Gauss.

Even according to the possibly apocryphal source, the issue is not infinitesimal calculus but rather the positional system for numbers.  Ball's account is completely off.  This should be emphasized.

@MikhailKatz I elaborated on that point. I think it's a bit tricky without knowing what Gauss actually said. There is a possibility that he did say something essentially of this sort and that in the actual context it does relate to calculus. Hand calculation, and numerical/number system strategies were a big part of practical calculus solutions, so there could be a connection. So the best I can do is warn of this being not a primarily sourced story (in the sense of provably coming from Gauss himself) at this point.

Whatever the actual quote, it seems like it would have been meant hyperbolically. Like when you make a silly mistake you think or say "Oh, I'm such an idiot!"

@Barmar I agree with this. I don't know German but he probably said something like "What a fool..."

@Barmar and zeynel. Please read my answer carefully. It is unclear that Gauss said anything of this sort at all. But if we do take the given source seriously (von Waltershaus) it is clear that he didn't call Achimedes an idiot or fool. So these kinds of baseless speculations only serve to confuse the careless reader and are unhelpful at best.

"How could he overlook that" is essentially the same thing. When I say "I'm such an idiot" it's exactly what I mean about myself.

Some sort of misunderstanding on Gauss' part, obviously. Babylonians used a positional sexagesimal numeral system starting around 2000BC, and apparently it was known to the greeks. Re "Greek Astronomy and Its Debt to the Babylonians"
Leonard W. Clarke The British Journal for the History of Science Vol. 1, No. 1 (Jun., 1962), pp. 65-77 (13 pages)
